# How to get value between two different tags using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to extract data present between a ending  tag and a 
 tag in below code snippet:

```
<td><b>First Type :</b>W<br><b>Second Type :</b>65<br><b>Third Type :</b>3</td>
```

What I need is : **W, 65, 3**

But the problem is that these values can be empty too, like-

```
<td><b>First Type :</b><br><b>Second Type :</b><br><b>Third Type :</b></td>
```

I want to get these values if present else an empty string

I tried making use of **nextSibling** and **find_next('br')** but it returned

```
 <br><b>Second Type :</b><br><b>Third Type :</b></br></br>
```

**and**

```
<br><b>Third Type :</b></br>
```

in case if values(W, 65, 3) are not present between the tags

```
</b> and <br>
```

All I need is that it should return a empty string if nothing is present between those tags.

Comment: Hey, `next_sibling` eventually works fine for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a `<b>` tag by `</b>` tag strategy, looking at what type of info their `next_sibling` contains.

I would just check whether their `next_sibling.string` is not `None`, and accordingly append the list :)

```
>>> html = """<td><b>First Type :</b><br><b>Second Type :</b>65<br><b>Third Type :</b>3</td>"""

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> b = soup.find_all("b")
>>> data = []
>>> for tag in b:
        if tag.next_sibling.string == None:
            data.append(" ")
        else:
            data.append(tag.next_sibling.string)
>>> data 
[' ', u'65', u'3'] # Having removed the first string
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I would search for a `td` object then use a `regex` pattern to filter the data that you need, instead of using `re.compile` in the `find_all` method.

Like this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """<td><b>First Type :</b>W<br><b>Second Type :</b>65<br><b>Third 
Type :</b>3</td>
<td><b>First Type :</b><br><b>Second Type :</b>69<br><b>Third Type :</b>6</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")

for o in soup.find_all('td'):
    match = re.findall(r'</b>\s*(.*?)\s*(<br|</br)', str(o))
    print ("%s,%s,%s" % (match[0][0],match[1][0],match[2][0]))
```

This pattern finds all text between the `</b>` tag and `<br>` or `</br>` tags. The `</br>` tags are added when converting the soup object to string.

This example outputs:

> > > W,65,3
> > >
> > > ,69,6

Just an example, you can alter to return an empty string if one of the regex matches is empty.

Comment: Its just a small snippet of the large html file i have. Is it efficient to  use **re** as the structure of the data containers,i.e., info between </b> and <br> tags, remains same throughout the html file?

Comment: Yes, it is efficient and you can't miss anything if replacing a re match with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [5]: [child for child in soup.td.children if isinstance(child, str)]
Out[5]: ['W', '65', '3']
```

Those text and tag are td's child, you can access them use `contents`(list) or `children`(generator)

```
In [4]: soup.td.contents
Out[4]: 
[<b>First Type :</b>,
 'W',
 <br/>,
 <b>Second Type :</b>,
 '65',
 <br/>,
 <b>Third Type :</b>,
 '3']
```

then you can get the text by test whether it's the instance of `str`

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<td><b>First Type :</b>W<br><b>Second Type :</b>65<br><b>Third Type :</b>3</td>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
td = soup.find('td')
string = str(td)
list_tags = string.split('</b>')
list_needed = []
for i in range(1, len(list_tags)):
    if list_tags[i][0] == '<':
        list_needed.append('')
    else:
        list_needed.append(list_tags[i][0])
print(list_needed)
#['W', '65', '3']
```

Because the values you want are always after the end of  tags it's easy to catch them this way, no need for re.